# Composer is stuck in downloading provides-2018

Tags: composer-php

Compose is stuck in the following line:

`Downloading https://packagist.org/p/provider-2018-04%24dd10232194c990065690aafbcbb7396b9c39818cd0ead5a962df3f0838c13d04.json`

when I do a `composer -vvv update`.

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was because it was downloading the packages from packagist using http and not https, so you can make this change with:

`composer config --global repo.packagist composer https://packagist.org`

Comment: Adding a description to explain why the OP should run this command would greatly improve you answer.

Comment: sorry, i was added the description

Comment: @raqaelFisabillahRamadhan Just saved me a lot of trouble. Thanks.